# Replacing a partition within a .img with another one

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, images, fdisk

I have 2 .img files (embedded Linux images, each with 2 partitions- a boot partition and a rootfs). I need to replace the rootfs partition in one with the other's.

How can I do this

1. In the .imgs directly
2. With the .imgs written to SD cards.

I would appreciate if answers included commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the partition you need to replace is at least the same size as the one you will copy. If your image files are *not* compressed, they can be mounted as loopback file systems using `kpartx`.

### Copying file systems across disk images

You'll need LVM2 for this to work. Let `disk1.img` and `disk2.img`, assuming both images are the exact same size in the following example:

```
# Let device mapper detect partitions on disk images
kpartx -a disk1.img
kpartx -a disk2.img

# Unmount source and destination file systems
umount /dev/mapper/loop?p?

# Copy source file system to destination
dd if=/dev/loop1p2 of=/dev/loop0p2 bs=512
# or:
# cat dev/loop1p2 > /dev/loop0p2

# Remove device nodes
kpartx -d disk1.img
kpartx -d disk2.img
```

If the source file system is smaller, you will have to extend the one on `/dev/mapper/loop0p2` using `resize2fs`. If the *destination* file system is smaller, then you'll have to shrink the source file system to the *exact same size* as the destination's using your partitioning tool of choice. I'd recommend `fdisk`.

**EDIT**: With the SD card detected as `/dev/mmcblk0` (assuming the destination is the second partition of the SD card, for instance) all you need to do is copy the file system from `/dev/mapper/loop0p2`, for instance, onto the second partition of the SD card, say `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

**EDIT**: If the destination file system is smaller, the source file system shall be reduced to fit the target partition.

### Shrinking the source file system

Assuming loop devices have been added with `kpartx -a` and *none is mounted*:

```
# Check file systems block count and size
tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/loop0p2 | grep -E 'Block (count|size)'
tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/loop1p2 | grep -E 'Block (count|size)'

# Shrink source file system to fit the destination
# (FS check is mandatory before shrinking)
fsck -f /dev/mapper/loop1p2
resize2fs /dev/mapper/loop1p2 <loop0p2 block count>

# Proceed with file system copy...
```

`resize2fs` will fail if there are not enough blocks to fit the requested size (although I never was in such a situation). Should block sizes differ, you may multiply `<block count>` by `<block size>` and append `B` to the result when passing the new file system size:

```
# Example: 123456 blocks, 4096 bytes per block
resize2fs /dev/mapper/loop1p2 $((123456*4096))B
```

Optionally you can shrink the source file system to its minimum size and then expand the destination file system to fit its partition, no calculation involved:

```
resize2fs -M /dev/mapper/loop1p2
# Do the copy ...
resize2fs /dev/mapper/loop0p2
```

Either will fail only if the operation is not possible.

You will most probably get an error at the end of the copy operation because the source partition has not been resized. It should normally do no harm as the kernel won't allow writing past the end of the allocated target partition.

You may want to be extremely careful and use `dd` to limit the amount of data to copy to the destination partition size (mind block size `bs` and `count'). I'll leave the command and arguments up to you as you have all you need for an educated guess ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot Nasha! I have been trying this way. My destination partition is smaller than the source partition. But, I can't figure out how to resize 'loop1p2' using fdisk. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You needn't resize the partition, only the file system. See my latest EDIT.

Comment: I was able to resize the partition following your advice. Everything went well until the 'dd' command returned: "write error: No space left on device". Though, it seemed like the write completed. 
However, when I booted the rootfs, I found that the files were corrupted. I'm very grateful you took the time to write this answer. Please help me.

Comment: The "No space left" error message is expected. However transferring filesystems should not yield corrupted files unless a) they're corrupted on the source or b) you did something wrong. Source and target filesystems must be unmounted while copying. To check the target filesystem integrity run fsck against it; there should be no errors. What option did you go? Resize to the minimum or to a calculated size?

Comment: Sincere apologies for the false alarm. I tried the above procedure again, with the 'cat' command instead of 'dd', and it all went well. I was able to boot the image. I did get the (No space equivalent) error again, but the image was written fine. Thanks a lot for your time and help. :)

Comment: Glad to see it worked :-). Pleasure to help.